# How to handle a new line when reading a file using Java

Tags: java, arrays, csv

I am trying to read a huge file where a *new line* is indicated by `no space`, `comma`, `new line character`, or anything.

> **Example:** line1element1, line1element2, line1element3, line2element1, line2element2, and so on..

The file is a `csv` and I am reading it like following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    String element;
    String filename = "E:\\csv.csv";
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(filename));
    scanner.useDelimiter(",");

    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        element = scanner.next();
        list.add(element);

    }
    System.out.print(list);
}
```

This causes issues because the `element50` in a line gets combined with `element51`, although it should be a new line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `BufferedReader` for this:

```
String filename = "E:\\csv.csv";
BufferedReader fileReader = null;

//Delimiter used in CSV file
final String DELIMITER = ",";

String line = "";
//Create the file reader
fileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename ));

//Read the file line by line
while ((line = fileReader.readLine()) != null)
{
    //Get all tokens available in line
    String[] tokens = line.split(DELIMITER);
    for(String token : tokens)
    {
        //Print all tokens
        System.out.println(token);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't I need a catch?

Comment: Also this outputs the data as just 1 big column rather than recognizing the multiple rows.

Comment: This is a horrible solution and CSV parsing has many intricacies. For starters, readLine wont work if any value comes with a newline character. String.split will incorrectly handle quoted values that contain the comma character. Use a CSV parser for this instead of creating your own.

Comment: Forgot to mention: this is also terribly slow. Try running this piece of code on a big file and see for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

USe a BufferedReader, not Scanner

```
File f= ...;
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
String line;
while ((line = br.nextLine()) != null) {
  String[] columns = line.split(",");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use **CSVParser** from Apache Commons or **OpenCSV**?

Examples here:

- [OpenCSV Example](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/)
- [Apache Commons example](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/user-guide.html)

If you insist on doing this manually, use BufferedReader as the other comments mention.

Answer (score -1):

From your description it seems your file does not have headers for each column. Use [uniVocity-parsers](http://www.univocity.com/pages/parsers-tutorial) to do this for you - it's 3 times faster than Commons CSV & OpenCSV and packed with features.

```
// you have many configuration options here - check the tutorial. By default values are trimmed and blank lines skipped.
CsvParserSettings settings = new CsvParserSettings();

CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(settings);

List<String[]> allRows = parser.parseAll(new FileReader(new File("/path/to/your/file.csv")));
```

Disclosure: I am the author of this library. It's open-source and free (Apache V2.0 license).